# Why does canola oil heat up in the microwave?

Tags: thermodynamics

**Introduction:** I read on Wikipedia's list of common misconceptions that microwaves work not by emitting the resonant frequency of water, but as a result of dielectric heating. As I understand it, this process heats a substance by emitting a constantly changing electric field, which makes the polar molecules in the substance attempt to align themselves with the field, thus introducing more molecular motion, that is, thermal energy. This makes me think that the heat introduced to the substance should be directly proportional to the polarity of the molecule. I then conducted a brief experiment:

**Method:**
I heated 25g of canola oil and 25g of water in plastic cups in a 1250 W microwave oven for 15 seconds each, measuring the temperatures before and after. I couldn't find the frequency of the waves emitted from the microwave, though I'm pretty sure it's the standard 2.45 GHz. If the frequency is necessary to know for sure, I think I could go back and partially melt a chocolate bar in it, finding the wavelength, and use the speed of light to find the frequency. (http://www.planet-science.com/categories/over-11s/physics-is-fun!/2012/01/measure-the-speed-of-light-using-chocolate.aspx)

**Data:**

|  | Water | Canola oil |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mass (g) | 25 | 25 |
| time in microwave (s) | 15 | 15 |
| initial temperature (C) | 25 | 24 |
| final temperature (C) | 51 | 33 |

**Results:**

Using estimated specific heat for canola oil (from https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/canola-oil and https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/10942910701586273) of 2.1 J/gK and 4.182 J/gK for water, it can be found that the change in energy of the water is:

q = mc(delta T)=(25 g)(4.182 J/gK)(26 K) = 2718 J

And the change of energy in the oil is:

q = mc(delta T)=(25 g)(2.1 J/gK)(9 K) = 472 J

So there was about six times more energy given to the water than the oil.

**Discussion:** This seems odd to me. First, if dielectric heating relies on polarity, why is the canola oil heating at all? Second, why is it heating as much as it is? I would think that the hydrogen bonds in the water are far more than six times as strong as the London dispersion forces within the oil. Is it because the oil is diluted with a polar substance? Is it because the lowered polarity makes it easier to move the molecules, and therefore impart heat? What should be expected to happen if a completely nonpolar material is microwaved?